# OpenID account not recognised if logged in to another account

Tags: support, openid, google

Steps to reproduce bug:

1. Create Stack Overflow account with gmail account one e.g. example1@gmail.com
2. Log out of SO.
3. Log in to gmail with account two e.g. example2@gmail.com
4. Try to log in to SO by manually entering OpenID for account one

I expected to be logged in with account one, but SO tried to use account two and complained that the OpenID entered was not associated with an SO account.

If I log out of gmail with account two and try again to manually enter OpenID for account one it works fine.

I'd like to be able to be logged in to gmail with account one and still be able to use SO with my OpenID based on another gmail account.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a Google problem; it won't let you OpenID authenticate with one account while you're logged into their websites with another. I don't think there's anything SO can do about that

Answer (score 2):

Try this order instead.

1. Log into your SO-recognized OpenID provider, and then log into Stack Overflow.
2. Log out of your SO-recognized OpenID provider, but *do not* log out of Stack Overflow. You can now continue acting in Stack Overflow.
3. Log into your other account at your OpenID provider. Now you're logged into SO on one account, but onto your provider as a separate!

As long as you don't get rid of your cookies, then you don't even need to repeat this process again because you'll retain your login to Stack Overflow.