# OpenID Endpoint Suddenly Not Found

Tags: support, openid, login

I'm using a delegate for MyOpenId, and over about the past day, I've encountered the "Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found." error when trying to log in.  I can log in with Google, but I still hit this problem even if I haven't [already logged in to Google](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61341/openid-account-not-recognised-if-logged-in-to-another-account) and I don't think of that as a permanent solution anyway.

I just finished a torrid time of determining [how to make my delegate OpenID work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips/63119#63119) with StackExchange sites, so I don't know what could be the cause this time.  Immediately afterward, I tried logging into [slashdot](http://slashdot.org/) and [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/), both of which support OpenID authentication, and both signed me in without a problem.

On my OpenID delegate page, I have the following in my `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="openid.server" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server" />
<link rel="openid.delegate" href="http://[OPENID].myopenid.com/" />
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="http://www.myopenid.com/server">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://[OPENID].myopenid.com/">
<meta http-equiv="X-XRDS-Location" content="http://www.myopenid.com/xrds?username=[OPENID].myopenid.com" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works OK for me when I enter palswim.net -- I get sent to myopenid.

I suspect your server is too slow to return data overseas at times; there are some timeouts to prevent denial of service login attacks (by entering thousands of bad "extra slow" openids).

You might try

1. measuring response time to your website from various sites
2. Putting the openid stuff on a nearly blank page which has FAST load time

also see:
[Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Comment: Yeah, it works for me now, too.  It was just a weird, 1-day error I guess.  But, slowness didn't seem to be an issue for me, at least, because I visited my page and it loaded without any speed issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've probably solved at least part of the issues.  It turns out that my site has been having DNS issues, about which I didn't know.  I don't know if it has fixed all of the OpenID issues I've had, but it certainly fixed the current one(s).

Comment: +1 for not dangling prepositions.

Comment: [Thunder Rabbit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/155993/thunder-rabbit) ~what are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with some less used stackexchange side in mai 2012. i was not able to login to http://meta.stackoverflow.com using myopenid.com any more.

accessing http://www.myopenid.com had very slow response- i got the answer after 22 seconds.

fortunately i had some local login-cookie for some other stackexchage site where i was still logged in. there i was abel to go to my account and added a second openid for my account.

now i am using this second openid to connect to meta.stackoverflow.com.

this way i have a backup account so i donot loose my stackexchange reputation when one openid-provider goes offline

Answer (score 0):

I found out that accidentally leaving out the <html> opening tag also yields the "No OpenID endpoint found" message when you use OpenID delegation. This is true for the DotNetOpenAuth library that Stack Overflow uses.

On the other hand, if the HTML is valid, the delegated OpenID login works even if only these two lines are to be found in the HTML header (for Google account in this case):

```
<link rel="openid2.provider" href="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?source=profiles">
<link rel="openid2.local_id" href="http://www.google.com/profiles/[YOUR-ACCOUNT]">
```