# Can't Log Into Stack Overflow Sites with Delegated OpenID

Tags: support, openid, login

I used to be able to log into Stack Overflow with my delegated OpenID (http://joshdick.net), but now I'm no longer able to.

I see this error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

I already found this question which seems directly related:

[OpenID Endpoint Suddenly Not Found](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64244/openid-endpoint-suddenly-not-found)

I also went through the points on this page; none of them seem to apply to me:

[Can't log in with my OpenID - Troubleshooting Tips](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/i-cant-log-in-with-my-openid-troubleshooting-tips)

Finally, I tried going to http://test-id.org to identify problems with the delegation setup but the site appears to be down as of this writing.

Thanks in advance for any help someone can provide!

Comment: Are `openid2.provider`/`openid2.local_id` supported? I use `openid.server`/`openid.delegate`, so I can confirm those work; I'm not sure about the ones you're using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out!

Sadly for some reason, my site was missing an opening <html> tag, and somehow the W3C validator didn't catch that.

I guess the missing <html> tag was preventing the appropriate <link> tags from being parsed correctly.

Anyway, all straightened out now.